# Output record id through form builder nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called "loans", which has many :vehicles. The model implementation for loan accepts nested attributes for vehicles through a nested form (provided through simple_form gem).

```
class Loan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :vehicles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :vehicles
end
```

.

```
class LoansController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @loan = Loan.new
    @loan.vehicles.build
  end

  def edit
    @loan = Loan.find(params[:id])
    @vehicle = @loan.vehicles
  end
end
```

Edit.html.erb:

```
<%= simple_form_for @loan, :html => {:class => "loan-edit-form"} do |f| %>
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :vehicles do |vehicle| %>
        <%= render 'vehicle_fields_edit', :f => vehicle %>
      <% end %>
<% end %>
```

_session_fields_edit.html.erb:

```
<div class="nested_vehicle" data-id="<%= @vehicle.id %>">
  <%= f.hidden_field :id, id: "vehicle_id", name: "vehicle_id" %>
  <div class="divider-top"></div>
  <div class="vehicle-number">
    Vehicle <span class="vehicle-count-rails"><%= f.index + 1 %></span>
  </div>
  ...... etc
</div>
```

The problem is I'm unable to show the database record ID of the vehicle in the edit nested form as I'm trying to do in the "data-id" attribute since I'm using simple form builder and not simply looping through the loan records using `@loan.vehicles.each do |vehicle|`.

Using a hidden field I'm able to show the record ID, however, it is shown within an input form field item, whereas I need to retrieve only the ID value alone for use within the data-id attribute.

I've tried `<%= f.id %>` but get a form builder error. How can I get the record ID whilst using form builder as I've described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, instead of `f.id`:

```
<%= f.object.id %>
```